# Firebase iOS -Key/Value pair isn't physically deleting from the database

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I hold all the usernames inside a separate node to run searches on when users search for a username. I deleted a name from the node eg. *pizzaMan*. The problem is even though it deletes, if I run a search on the deleted name from within my app it says it's available but when I physically look inside the database it shows it's still physically there (meaning it shouldn't be available). **How is that possible?**

```
@IBAction func deleteUsernameButtonTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {

    // the user's username is pizzaMan
    let username = usernamesRef?.child("pizzaMan")
    userName?.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in

        if snapshot.exists() {

            let key = snapshot.key

            username?.child(key).removeValue()
            print("username: \(key) has been deleted\n")
        }
    })
}
```

The username pizzaMan has been deleted but physically inside the database it shows it's still there.

[image]

[image]

```
let checkUsernameTextField = UITextField()
checkUsernameTextField.addTarget(self, action: #selector(handleSearchForUsername), for: .editingChanged) 

@objc func handleSearchForUsername() {

    // now search for pizzaMan inside a textField
    usernamesRef?.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in

        if snapshot.exists() {

            print("name is NOT avail")
        } else {
            print("name IS available") // this prints when searching for pizzaMan even though it's inside the db??
        }
    })
}
```

If I try to obtain it lets me and just writes over the old value with whatever the new value is but it still shouldn't show up inside the database once removed.

Comment: Try Removing Reference as soon as value is deleted, Second Do really an observe event here is necessary ?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem lies inside your delete func if I am understanding your issue.

Let me reiterate what I think you are saying. You want pizzaMan's node to be completely removed, yes? Try this:

```
@IBAction func deleteUsernameButtonTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {

    // the user's username is pizzaMan
    if let username = usernamesRef as? DatabaseReference{
         username.child("usernames/pizzaMan").removeValue()
    }
    else{
         print("Errors")
    }

}
```

Is that what you intend to do?

Comment: yes you at correct about what I’m  intending on doing. I’ll try your answer in an hour or so and get back to. From looking at your answer it seems that the problem was caused by me instantiating the key before deleting it. I hope your answer works

Comment: If it doesn't I am here to help. The issue was, from what I see, is your were going to: username/pizzaMan/pizzaMan <- Remove. This never existed so nothing was removed; however, it didn't fail to remove nothing so you didn't get an error. I just went back one and if this works you can easily create a `func` to assign whatever key you are trying to delete or if you want to delete it if the `snapshot.exists()` returns `true', I can edit my answer for you.

Comment: sore for the late response. I tried exactly like you posted but the same problem exists as the way I explained. It removes/deletes the key/value pair but yet when I look in the database it’s right there in front of me. However when I search it says it’s available. Btw the search works fine for anything else. If I search for another name that I haven’t deleted it says it’s not unavailable and if I search for a name that doesn’t exist it says it’s available. The problem only arises after I delete it.

Comment: Are you setting it somewhere else? Since you are using `observeSingleEvent` you won't see a change to your local copy of the database (if you have one). You might need to provide a little more code.

Comment: The only time I set it is when the user first signs up and picks a username. After they sign in the vc is deallocated. I am using a singleton to manage everything from Firebase but that particular call to create a username should get destroyed upon deallocation. The code you see is literally the exact same code I use.

Comment: I think I missed this - try `username?.child("usernames/pizzaMan").removeValue()`. I didn't see your username node.

Comment: No, I meant the initialization of `usernameRef`. What is it equal to?

Comment: You mean this? Database.database().reference()?.child(“usernames”).updateChildValues(usernameDict)

Comment: Is that what `usernameRef` is equal to? The declaration of your variable `usernameRef`? Would be something like `let usernameRef = Database.database().reference()`.

Comment: Well it’s pretty much the same thing because the the username var holds the value of the the usernameRef. From there you would just declare usernameRef.updateChildValues(usernameDict). But yes. Although everything runs through a singleton. So the usernameRef is a static function that just returns the usernameRef.

Comment: Correct, but you can confirm it's at most equal to `Database.database().reference()`? Exactly?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/176828/discussion-between-torewin-and-lance-samaria).

Comment: Yes, the root for the db is definitely the Firebase chain you just added. If it wasn’t it wouldn’t post anything to the db.